# shortcut technique to solve algebric problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

```
If we multiply three consecutive numbers, we get 120. what the summation of those numbers?
```

Is there any shortcut way of solving this problem without doing much calculation?

Comment: Hint:  write the three numbers as $\{n-1,n,n+1\}$.  Look for integer roots for the cubic.

Comment: what is the benefit of taking x-1,x and x+1 instead of x,x+1,x+2? @Nikunj

Comment: The algebra is simpler.  $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n$.

Comment: The statement, instead of it being $n^3-n=120$ is instead written as $x^3+3x^2+2x=120$.  The first form is what is called a "depressed cubic" and is generally easier to work with.  For instance, knowing that $n$ must be an integer implies that since $n^3-n=120$ that $n$ divides evenly into $120$, so $n$ must be one of $2,3,4,5,6,8,10,$ but could not be something like $7,9,11$.  Such information is less immediate in the form with $x,x+1,x+2$

Comment: For the number $120$, there is no better way than doing some quick mental arithmetic. But suppose that we were told that the product $(n-1)(n)(n+1)$ of three consecutive integers is $B$, where $B$ is big, and we wanted the sum $3n$.  Then the sum is $3\lceil \sqrt[3]{B}\rceil$, where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function, the smallest integers $\ge x$.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring, $120=2^3\cdot3\cdot5$.

We need consecutive factors. At a glance, they could be $3,4,5$ or $4,5,6$.

Hope this fits in your requirements.

---

**With the help of a calculator**:

You can observe that $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n$ is close to $n^3$. As $\sqrt[3]{120}=4.93\cdots$, you can conjecture $n=5$.

Comment: "We need consecutive factors. At a glance, they could be 3,4,5 or 4,5,6.. will you please clarify? @Yves Daoust

Comment: @user6216509: hem, $2,3,5$ aren't consecutive so you can imagine other combinations, with a little mental effort.

Answer (score 0):

Three consecutive integers can be written as $x-1, x, x+1$. Thus, we have:
$$(x-1)x(x+1)=120$$
First, note that $x > 0$ because otherwise, the product would be $0$ or negative since the product of three negative consecutive integers would be negative.
$$x^3-x-120=0$$
Use synthetic division with positive integer roots in order to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the middle of the three consecutive numbers.

They tell us that $(n-1)\cdot n\cdot (n+1) = 120$

We want to find $(n-1)+n+(n+1)$

This is more convenient in my opinion than letting the numbers be $n,n+1,n+2$ since things simplify nicely.

The statements simplified are:

if $n^3-n=120$, then find $3n$

As for continuing to solve, one could use heavier tools like [cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), or you could make the assumption that since the question was being asked that you expect there to be a positive integer value $n$ such that this is true.  Notice that $3^3=27, 4^3=64, 6^3=216$, so $4^3-4$ is too small to be $120$ and $6^3-6$ is too big to be $120$...  This implies that...

Comment: The value must be a little above $\sqrt[3]{120}$ (it's actually $\lceil\sqrt[3]{120}\rceil$).